# Permanently moving a domain to subdirectory without affecting the SEO, Google Analytics

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, server, google-analytics, seo

I have a wordpress website [footballfriendsonline.com](http://footballfriendsonline.com) and it has almost 22,000 blog posts running with SEO google analytics for the past 6 years, all the contents are scattered in almost all social media and backlinked in a lot of websites. The issue is I'm planning to start afresh news aggregator site with the same old web address [1](http://footballfriendsonline.com) I want to move the old blog contents to the subdirectory i.e. [footballfriendsonline.com/blog](http://footballfriendsonline.com/blog) and I want to run the same old blogging in [2](http://footballfriendsonline.com/blog) without affecting the SEO and also want to run the fresh startup aggregator site in [1](http://footballfriendsonline.com).

I tried with 301 redirections by updating .htaccess file and I failed in getting desired output.

Anyone, please help me with this...

Comment: There are many way to movie domain. bu you are able to do movie by wp all in one migration plugin. which is transfer all your blogs and another SEO details also.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DaImTo Thanks. will update in https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that.. Transparently redirect your root directory to a subdirectory...

1. Log into cPanel
2. File Manager
3. Edit the .htaccess file
4. Add the following code to the .htaccess file:

   ```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?footballfriendsonline.com$
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdirectory/$1
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?footballfriendsonline.com$
   RewriteRule ^(/)?$ blog/index.php [L]
   ```

this will work for you. please check...